# "redundant cast to java.lang.Object" warning for necessary cast

Tags: java, casting, compiler-warnings, compiler-bug, ambiguous-call

Consider this *[Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)* :

```
interface Code {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        symbol(
            String.valueOf(
                true ? 'a' :
                true ? 'b' :
                true ? 'c' :
                fail()
            )
        );
    }
    private static void symbol(String symbol) {
        System.out.println(symbol);
    }
    private static <R> R fail() {
        throw null;
    }
}
```

(Being near minimal, `true` is a stand in for a useful boolean expression. We can ignore beyond the first `? :` (in the real code, there are lots).)

This 'obviously' gives the error.

```
4: reference to valueOf is ambiguous
  both method valueOf(java.lang.Object) in java.lang.String and method valueOf(char) in java.lang.String match
```

Okay let's fix it. It's the `String.valueOf(Object)` overload I want - I might later want to add:

```
            true ? "sss" :
```

(In fact I did have something similar earlier, but have now removed the feature.)

```
        String.valueOf((Object)(
            true ? 'a' :
            fail()
        ))
```

This gives the warning:

```
4: redundant cast to java.lang.Object
```

Is this a bug in the compiler warning or error, and how do I fix it so *the code is reasonable* and there are no warnings or errors?

**(Edits:** I've change the MRE slightly. `throws Throwable` was from a [template](https://github.com/tackline/Little-Bean). The real code does use literal chars* and `String.valueOf` Elsewhere it uses the `String.valueOf(char)` overload, so `toString()` is problematic (oh Java!). The code avoids global state, such as `System.out`, and `symbol` and `fail` are in different classes. The "switch" is of a non-enumerable type. `fail` is a companion to an assert-like method, so that's why it throws an (unchecked non-null) exception internally.

How I actually fixed it was, unrelatedly, I rearranged code so there were some literal strings in there too. Otherwise, I would have used the pointless `Object.class.cast` equivalent of `(Object)`. What I really want to know is: wtf?

*Actually the *real real* code goes through a lexer for a different language that doesn't distinguish between literal char, string, various numbers, boolean, enums, etc. Why would it?**)**

Comment: Isn't `true ? 'a' : fail()` equivalent to just `'a'`?  What is the purpose of this construct?

Comment: @JimGarrison `true` is just to make the example code simple. The real code has lines like `type == SymbolToken.assign       ? '='  :`.

Comment: I think you need to provide an example that more closely approximates your use case.  Note that changing the `'a'` to `"a"` removes the warning, but I assume you know that already.   Please share more of your mental model of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JimGarrison Then it gets obscure. It's a preprocessor for itself. `"a`"` is converted to `'a'` because `"abc"` is indistinguishable from `'abc` and so the preprocessor (which is just a stop gap) guesses that a single letter is a `char` constant. In any case, in an equivalent situation the `char` could be return by some random function.

Comment: Well, without a more concrete example of your true objective, I think the best you're going to get is the embedded cast from `char` to `Object`.  Could this be an XY Problem?

Comment: @JimGarrison No. No it isn't. Would it help if I replaced the `main` with a method parameterised with the values and added several `? :`s.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error about an “ambiguous method invocation” is correct since Java 8.

Even before Java 8, you could write

```java
char c = fail();
Object o = fail();
```

without compiler errors. When you pass a conditional like `condition? 'a': genericMethod()` to a method like `String.valueOf(…)`, the compiler inferred `<Object>` for `fail()` and picked `String.valueOf(Object)` due to its limited type inference.

But Java 8 introduced [Poly Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.3):

> The type of a standalone expression can be determined entirely from the contents of the expression; in contrast, the type of a poly expression may be influenced by the expression's target type ([§5 (Conversions and Contexts)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html)).

Both, an invocation of a generic method and a conditional containing a poly expression (i.e. the invocation of a generic method), are poly expressions.

So trying to invoke `String.valueOf(char)` is valid with that conditional, as we can infer `<Character>` for `fail()`. Note that neither method is applicable in a [strict invocation context](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3), as both variants require a boxing or unboxing operation. In a [*loose* invocation context](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3), both, `String.valueOf(Object)` and `String.valueOf(char)` are applicable, as it doesn’t matter whether we unbox the `Character` after invoking `fail()` or box the `char` of the literal `'a'`.

Since `char` is not a subtype of `Object` and `Object` is not a subtype of `char`, neither method, `String.valueOf(Object)` nor `String.valueOf(char)`, is [more specific](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5), hence, a compiler error is generated.

---

Judging about the warning is more difficult, as there is no formal standard for warnings. In my opinion, every compiler warning that claims that a source code artifact was obsolete despite the code will not do the same after removing it (or removing it will even introduce errors), is incorrect. Interestingly, the warning does already exist in Java 7’s version of `javac`, where removing the cast truly makes no difference, so perhaps, it’s a leftover that needs to be updated.

---

Workarounds for the issue depend on the context and there’s not enough information about it. Mind that there is only one branch needed that is not assignable to `char`, to make the method `String.valueOf(char)` inapplicable. That will happen, as soon as you insert the branch that evaluates to `String`. You could also use `SurroundingClass.<Object>fail()` to get to the same type that pre-Java 8 compilers inferred.

Or drop the generic signature entirely, as it is not needed here. The generic method `fail()` seems to be a work-around to have a throwing method in an expression context. A cleaner solution would be a factory method for the expression, e.g.

```java
class Code {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SpecificExceptionType {
        System.out.println(
            String.valueOf(switch(0) {
                case 0 -> 'a';
                case 1 -> 'b';
                case 2 -> 'c';
                default -> throw fail();
            })
        );
    }
    private static SpecificExceptionType fail() {
        return new SpecificExceptionType();
    }
    static class SpecificExceptionType extends Exception {
    }
}
```

If switch expressions are not feasible, you could use

```java
System.out.println(
    String.valueOf(
        true ? 'a' :
        true ? 'b' :
        true ? 'c' :
        Optional.empty().orElseThrow(Code::fail)
    )
);
```

Both have the advantage of being specific about the actual type of potentially thrown exceptions and don’t need resorting to unchecked exceptions or `throws Throwable` declarations. The second might feel hacky, but not more than defining a generic method that never returns anything.

Of course, there are other possibilities to solve it, if you just accept the introduction of more code, like a dedicated helper method for the string conversion without overloads or a non-generic wrapper method for the throwing method. Or a temporary variable or type casts or explicit types for the generic invocations, etc. Further, when using `"" + (expression)` or `(expression).toString()` instead of `String.valueOf(expression)`, the expression is not a poly expression, hence, not pro­du­cing an “ambiguous method invocation” error.

Of course, since this is a false warning, you could also keep the cast and add a `@SuppressWarnings("cast")` to the method (and wait until this gets fixed by the compiler developers).

Comment: I don't claim to be able to follow the JLS there. It's odd that adding a dummy `Optional.empty()` works for `orElseThrow`. I hope you get the 'lifejacket' badge.

Comment: For a chained method invocations like `.empty().orElseThrow(…)`, the type inference still is limited for the first part(s), so it infers `Object` here. This still is a kludge, the switch expression is the way to go, as it allows to integrate the throwing branch into the expression without a pseudo return type. Since pattern matching is a planned feature, this solution will be applicable to other conditions than just a number in the future.

Comment: @Holger I don't understand why a cast to Object is needed here. Shouldn't `lub(char, Object) = Object` automatically?
Even casting it to `R` works but why?

public static <R> void main(String[] args) {
String.valueOf(true ? 'a' : true ? 'b': true ? 'c' : (R)fail())
}

Comment: @ThirumalaiParthasarathi why do you assume the second type to be Object?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the two branches of the ternary operator return different types.

How about this:

```
    System.out.println(
        String.valueOf(
            true ? (Object)'a' : fail()
        )
    );
```

Comment: That should work, but that's a lot of code if there are many lines of `? :`.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline compared to what? All of your alternatives contain at least as much code as that.

Comment: @Holger As mentioned in the question, I want to be able to add other `? :`s into the chain (and have in the real code).

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline like `a? (Object)b: c? d: e? f: g`? Where’s the problem?

Comment: @Holger To do it only for the first one would be weird, wouldn't it? Particularly when it's a question of selecting the correct overload.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline you are changing the topic. But the biggest problem with your question is that you keep on insisting that your real life case is different, but don’t show your real life case. E.g. I assume, the real life case is not invoking `String.valueOf`, so which method are you actually invoking and does it need to be that heavily overloaded? Why does it matter which overload is invoked? Second, your real life case is not `'a'`, so what is actually? A parameter? Can’t you declare it as `Object` in the first place? Truly a constant? How about declaring a named constant, using `Object`?

Comment: @Holger The real code, which doesn't really matter, does use `String.valueOf`, but it doesn't use `System.out.println` nor is it directly in `main`. The symbols were literal characters in `=()[]+**/.!&|:;@?^%` (`*` is the value for two conditions).

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline then, I don’t get your requirements. Why does it matter whether inserting `condition? "...":` would turn the code from using `String.value(char)` to `String.value(Object)`? The behavior would be the same. Or just replace `String.valueOf` with `"" +` and you’ve solved the problem with even shorter code. Or, since there’s no `null` involved, use `(…).toString()` instead of `String.valueOf(…)`.

Comment: @Holger `String.valueOf` is necessary in the case of all literals are characters but the `fail()` remains. `String.valueOf` is consistent with the rest of the codebase. Also `"" +` always looks a hack and `.toString` (and anything at the `fail()` end) is a bit far from the action.

Answer (score 3):

Explicitly boxing the character is one possibility:

```
class Code {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(
                String.valueOf(
                        true ? Character.valueOf('a') : fail()
                )
        );
    }
    private static <R> R fail() {
        throw null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That should work, but that's a lot of code if there are many lines of `? :`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer to a simple question:

```
class Code {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println((
                true ? 'a' :
                true ? 'b' :
                true ? 'c' :
                fail()).toString()
        );
    }
    private static <R> R fail() {
        throw null;
    }
    
}
```

This code works as long as you do not have any `null` values. To cover also `null` values you would need to inroduce an additional method:

```
class Code {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(valueOf(
                true ? 'a' :
                true ? 'b' :
                true ? 'c' :
                fail()
            )
        );
    }
    private static <R> R fail() {
        throw null;
    }
    
    static String valueOf(Object object) {
        return String.valueOf(object);
    }
}
```

Both solutions do not require to edit the many lines of `? :`

Neither the compiler warning nor the error is a bug. In the error case you give the compiler too less information for the selection of the right method, in the second attempt you tell the compiler to cast an Object to an Object which is unnecessary and worth to produce at least a warning ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the call with a Supplier to get a way with:

```
class Code {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(((Supplier<Object>) () ->
                true ? 'a' :
                        false ? 'b' :
                                false ? 'c' :
                                        fail()).get());
    }
    private static <R> R fail() { throw null; }
 }
```

Comment: Cunning. Made me wonder whether there is an identity static method. `new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode(Object)` calls `toString` on its argument for `toString`. Better `Object.class.cast(Object)` works and is more or less equivalent to the original code.

Comment: +500 bounty rep. This answer inspired `Object.class.cast`. Inspired is better than just handed on a plate, because it makes me feel good about myself.:)

Answer (score 1):

Extract the result of the expression to a local variable:

```
T obj =
        true ? 'a' :
                true ? 'b' :
                        true ? 'c' : fail();
System.out.println(String.valueOf(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

`'a'` is not a `String` notation; replace that with `"a"` (and I also don't fully understand the use case - or maybe would write it whole different using the regex engine). However, in order to avoid pointless casting ...simply check with `instanceof`, what you are even trying to cast. Alike this, there is little space for ambiguous calls and useless casting back and forth.

Answer (score -1):

If I ignore my forward looking requirement for `String` I could write:

```
        String.valueOf((Character)(
            true ? 'a' :
            fail()
        ))
```

To handle both `char` and `String` I can use the *weird*:

```
        String.valueOf((Comparable<?>)(
            true ? 'a' :
            fail()
        ))
```

Or use Java Serialization for something useful:

```
        String.valueOf((java.io.Serializable)(
            true ? 'a' :
            fail()
        ))
```

**It should presumably considered a bug**, but I can't be bothered fighting bugs.java.com.

An alternative fix is to introduce a unnecessary local:

```
    Object symbol = 
            true ? 'a' :
            fail();
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(symbol));
```

It shouldn't be necessary, but it is possible to make the type parameter to `fail()` explicit and avoid any nasty explicit casts:

```
        String.valueOf(
            true ? 'a' :
            Code.<Object>fail()
        )
```

Lovely syntax! Alternatively, `fail()` could have a redundant cast...